# How to replace the first element of the `kill-ring` by a modification of it?

Tags: regular-expressions, replace, string, kill-ring

I am trying to modify the string that is to yanked

My goal is to modify certains paths *before* yanking, in order to transform them in relative to path actual buffer file.

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325713/looking-for-a-replace-in-string-function-in-elisp), I tried this simple script :

```
(setq tmp (car kill-ring-yank-pointer))
;;(message tmp)

(defun replace-in-string (what with in)
  (replace-regexp-in-string (regexp-quote what) with in nil 'literal))
(replace-in-string "C:\\Users\\Julien Fernandez\\Dropbox\\JULIEN" "../.." tmp)
(message tmp)
```

In my `kill-ring`, I have right now :

```
C:\Users\Julien Fernandez\Dropbox\JULIEN\Screenshots\Emacs\2021-02-03_16-48-43 - Code.png
```

I get as a result :

[image]

Where the file name has been modified, but obviously not as intended.

What should I do ?

PS : I discovered that I did not have to substitute *every* `\` in `'/' in the path, something like :

```
../..\Path\to\file.txt
```

works fine ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replace-regexp-in-string` does *not* do an in-place replacement. `C-h f` tells us that it returns a *new* string:

> Return a new string containing the replacements.

It sounds like what you want to do is replace the first element of the `kill-ring` by the result of calling `replace-regexp-in-string` (which is a different string from the one that is currently the first `kill-ring` element).

You need to do something like this, with the string you've created:

```lisp
(setq kill-ring  (cons (replace-in-string
                         "C:\\Users\\Julien Fernandez\\Dropbox\\JULIEN"
                         "../.."
                         (car kill-ring))
                       (cdr kill-ring)))
```

---

You could instead actually modify the `kill-ring` list structure, like this, but that's generally not a great idea:

```lisp
(setcar kill-ring (replace-in-string
                     "C:\\Users\\Julien Fernandez\\Dropbox\\JULIEN"
                     "../.."
                     (car kill-ring)))
```

Comment: Hi Drew, what's the difference between the first and the second setting?

Comment: @Drew : thx, it works... And I clearly understood my mistake ! I would be glad to understand the difference between the two proposition as well, as per Arch Stanton question.