# Modify the first element of the kill-ring

Tags: kill-ring, insert, filenames

I have stored in my clipboard a path to an image, which I want to paste inside emacs.

I would like to modify the path to change/postpone/prepone some stuff before yanking.

Following my previous question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63155/how-to-replace-the-first-element-of-the-kill-ring-by-a-modification-of-it), I tried

```
  (defun replace-in-string (what with in)
   (replace-regexp-in-string (regexp-quote what) with in nil 'literal)) 
  (defun paste-image-link ()
     (interactive)
     (let ((tmp  (car kill-ring))))
     (setq tmp (replace-in-string  "E:\\Dropbox\\JULIEN\\01.Emacs"
                             "../.."
                             tmp))
     (setq tmp (concat "[[file:" tmp "]]"))
     (setq kill-ring  (cons tmp (cdr kill-ring)))
     (yank)                               
     )
   (global-set-key (kbd "M-i")  'paste-image-link)
```

My goal is to change the absolute path to a relative path and add `[[file:` before.

For example, this :

```
E:\Dropbox\JULIEN\01.Emacs\02.Emacs screenshots\2021-04-04_02-23-12_vivaldi.png
```

should become :

```
[[file:../..\02.Emacs screenshots\2021-04-04_02-23-12_vivaldi.png]]
```

I am obviously making trivial mistakes about `let` and `setq`statements because I get instead :

```
[[file:[[file:[[file:[[file:[[file:[[file:[[file:(car kill-ring)]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
```

and the number of `[[file:`before is growing each time i try

what should I do ?

Addendum : *besides* i would like to add a line before to finally get

```
#+ATTR_ORG: :width 300px
[[file:../..\02.Emacs screenshots\2021-04-04_02-23-12_vivaldi.png]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Mostly your problem was misplaces parens: too many `)` here:

```lisp
(let ((tmp  (car kill-ring))))
```

Use `paren-mode` to see which parens balances which parens.

---

Standard function `kill-new` replaces the head of the `kill-ring` if you give it a second arg of non-`nil`.  So `(kill-new "xxx" t)` replaces the head of the `kill-ring` with `xxx`.

So try this:

```lisp
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((new  (format "[[file:%s]]" (replace-in-string
                                     "E:\\Dropbox\\JULIEN\\01.Emacs" "../.."
                                     (car kill-ring)))))
    (kill-new new t)))
```

You can add the `yank` or whatever to do that and add whatever other lines you want.

---

But a guess is that maybe you don't really need to change the kill-ring, you just want to be able to grab its head and from that produce a different string to then insert.  That you can do directly, using `insert` after getting the head of the ring and from that getting the string you want to insert.

---

Also, it's pretty unusual to modify `kill-ring` entries.  Usually it's enough, if you need something on the ring, just to put it there, not caring about what other elements are already on the ring.  Use `kill-new` (without second arg) to add a to the front of the ring.

---

Finally, if you're using file names ("paths"), just use `/` always, in Emacs, as the directory separator char, not `\\`, even on MS Windows. Emacs just does the right thing - there's pretty much never any need to use `\\` for that.

Comment: thank you very much. I will try it.

Comment: Upvoted Drew's superbly comprehensive answer, which I think you should accept. I would just add this: I think you need to use `replace-regexp-in-string`, not your `replace-in-string`, using a regex that intelligently strips out a leading `[[file:` if it's already present, so that repeated invocations don't keep prefixing more and more copies of `[[file:`.